FastAPI Azure Auth - Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption
I have followed this sample as is:
https://intility.github.io/fastapi-azure-auth/
However I get following error:
AADSTS9002325: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption.
As far as I can read this is related to the redirects uris not matching.
Fast API Open app reg:

Fast API app reg:

However those should match. And ideas how to solve or troubleshoot this?

Code:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi_azure_auth import SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer
from pydantic import AnyHttpUrl, computed_field
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Security

from pydantic import AnyHttpUrl
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings

from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from typing import AsyncGenerator


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS: list[str | AnyHttpUrl] = ['http://localhost:8000']
    OPENAPI_CLIENT_ID: str = "  "
    APP_CLIENT_ID: str = "xxx"
    TENANT_ID: str = "xxx"
    SCOPE_DESCRIPTION: str = "user_impersonation"

    @computed_field
    @property
    def SCOPE_NAME(self) -> str:
        return f'api://{self.APP_CLIENT_ID}/{self.SCOPE_DESCRIPTION}'

    @computed_field
    @property
    def SCOPES(self) -> dict:
        return {
            self.SCOPE_NAME: self.SCOPE_DESCRIPTION,
        }

    class Config:
        env_file = '.env'
        env_file_encoding = 'utf-8'
        case_sensitive = True

settings = Settings()

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI) -> AsyncGenerator[None, None]:
    """
    Load OpenID config on startup.
    """
    await azure_scheme.openid_config.load_config()
    yield


app = FastAPI(
    swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_url='/oauth2-redirect',
    swagger_ui_init_oauth={
        'usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant': True,
        'clientId': settings.OPENAPI_CLIENT_ID,
    },
)

app = FastAPI()

if settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS:
    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=[str(origin) for origin in settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS],
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=['*'],
        allow_headers=['*'],
    )

azure_scheme = SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer(
    app_client_id=settings.APP_CLIENT_ID,
    tenant_id=settings.TENANT_ID,
    scopes=settings.SCOPES,
)


@app.get("/", dependencies=[Security(azure_scheme)])
async def root():
    return {"whoIsTheBest": "DNA Team is"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('main:app', reload=True)


Set http://localhost:8000/docs in the web Redirect URI, as shown in this image.


I get following error: AADSTS9002325: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption.

To resolve the above issue, I added the below redirect URL to the Web Platform in the Api App registration.
http://localhost:8000/docs


After adding the redirect URL, I ran the application.

After clicking the Authorize button, I selected my account.

I successfully logged in without any issues.


Thanks appreciated. I have edited main post to include på auth settings. And I tried adding a web platform too as shown. However same. Do you run with two app registrations or only a single for both the API and the Open API?

@ThomasSegato I ran with two app registration.

Thanks. Would it be possible to see screenshots of both and see your code? Thanks in advance.
